# What are the default values for data types in Java?

Tags: java, primitive

I am very new to Java having always issue with data types. So what are the *default* values for all data types in Java?

Comment: 1st link suggested by a google search: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 17):

```
byte        0
short       0
int         0
long        0
float       0.0f
double      0.0d
char        '\u0000'
boolean     false
```

Answer (score 9):

http://javaignite.com/post/66/default-values-for-primitives-in-java

primitives dont have null value. default have for an int is 0.

```
if(person.getId()==0){}
```

Default values for primitives in java:

Data Type   Default Value (for fields)

```
byte                0
short               0
int                 0
long                0L
float               0.0f
double              0.0d
char               '\u0000'
boolean             false
```

Objects have null as default value.