# What will happen if none or only some fields are initialized in a constructor

Tags: java

The purpose of a constructor is initializing values for the fields, setting the initial state of the object. So what will happen if some fields or all fields were not initialized in the constructor?

Is it calling a default constructor provided by the JVM before the user defined constructor?

So, in this example, what would be output?

```
class Name{
      int x;
      boolean y;


      Name(){
      // no initialize
     }

     public static void main(){
        Name n = new Name();
        System.out.println(n.x + ", " + n.y);
     }

 }
```

Comment: primitive variables/fields have default values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class-level fields (instance or static fields) get default values assigned to them. This means that if the constructor or instance (or static) initialization blocks don't explicitly initialize these fields, the default values will remain.

In your case:

```
class Name{
      int x;     //default value for int is 0
      boolean y; //default value for boolean is false
```

In other words, your output should be `0, false`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151017/what-is-default-values-for-data-type-in-java) has details on the actual default values for primitive types. For Object data types, the default value is `null` (see also the [data types documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

Comment: Yes that is correct but did those default values were assigned to them by JVM provided default constructor at any point (interenally) before user define constructor

Comment: @IshwarMahawar The "default constructor" is just what the compiler adds for you when you don't explicitly declare a constructor. It would be exactly the same thing as your current `Name(){}` (except that it would be `public`). In other words, the JVM will assign the default values when it creates the object (before any constructor is run).

Comment: Yes that what i am saying...creating an object means writing in code  [ new Classname() ] which will call no arg constructor.. so when will it assign..?

Comment: @IshwarMahawar I see. I'm talking about creating the object as in *allocating memory for it* and setting default values in fields (when operations related to `new Classname()` are actually run by the JVM, and that includes more than running the code in the constructor)